# Avoiding for loop to create array

Tags: python, arrays, function

I am trying to create a complex array from an array that has real and complex data interlaced while avoiding a loop

```
data[0]=real, data[1]=imaginary,..

window[0]=complex(data[0],data[1]) # or data[0]+1j*data[1]
```

I'm very new to python and still getting used to the indexing/slicing?, I've tried:

```
window[150-1::-1]=data[0::2]+1j*data[1::2]
```

With the error being:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'
```

Now I have gotten a for loop to work but it seems to slow down the program considerably, hence why I am looking for a way without a loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do `window[150-1::-1] = [r + c * 1j for r, c in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])]`. In any case, if you are going to operate with numerical arrays a lot you may want to check out NumPy.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. I am using NumPy for fft and log10 what should I also be looking into using from NumPy?